# Why do I not a access to regular bash programs in my docker container

Tags: docker

I'm fiddling around with installing some small programs in a docker container.

Currently, I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install vim -y
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install gzip -y

WORKDIR "/root"

RUN wget https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/releases/download/4.4.1/spotbugs-4.4.1.tgz

RUN gunzip -c spotbugs-4.4.1.tgz | tar xvf -

CMD ["ls"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Which creates a image that contains some specific files i need to run.

I then build my container:

```
sudo docker build . --tag img
```

And then I run it:

```
 sudo docker run -t -d img
```

And after running it, I open a shell session in it:

```
sudo docker exec -it idhere /bin/bash
```

Once I this session, I am able to do `whoami`, `ls` and `cd`.
But now i need to navigate to one specific file on this computer and run a bash file, I need to run it with sudo, since I get persmission denied:

```
root@0e92aab9b906:~/spotbugs-4.4.1/bin# ./spotbugs
bash: ./spotbugs: Permission denied
root@0e92aab9b906:~/spotbugs-4.4.1/bin# sudo ./spotbugs
bash: sudo: command not found
```

But it doesnt know what sudo is? Why is this, does it not have access to regular bash programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `Permission denied` error because `~/spotbugs-4.4.1/bin/spotbugs` does not have the execute bit set.  Add the line `RUN chmod +x /root/spotbugs-4.4.1/bin/spotbugs` in your Dockerfile to add the execute bit for that file in your Docker image.

Also, the `sudo` package is not installed in that Docker image.  You should not need it, but if you really wanted it, you could install it just like the other tools you installed by adding the line `RUN apt-get install sudo -y` to your Dockerfile.